# My Flutter desktop application suddenly crashed with an error message

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a flutter desktop application and it is running fine, but now it suddenly crashes sometimes with an error message

This is the screenshot of error:

[image]

Here flutter doctor -v result:

```html
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889], locale en-PK)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\SDK\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (5 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.9)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.32106.194
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.81
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 104.0.1293.54

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

I am unable to configure the cause of this error message and application crashing.
Anyone please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: implement crash logging mechanism to log crashes so that you can debug. Without crash log it's hard to debug !!

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I do that? This  crash logging.